# Auto-detect the delimiter in a CSV file using pd.read_csv

Tags: python, pandas, csv, delimiter

Is there a way for `read_csv` to auto-detect the delimiter? numpy's [`genfromtxt`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html) does this.

My files have data with single space, double space and a tab as delimiters. `genfromtxt()` solves it, but is slower than pandas' `read_csv`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Option 1**

Using `delim_whitespace=True`

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', delim_whitespace=True)
```

---

**Option 2**

Pass a regular expression to the `sep` parameter:

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', sep='\s+')
```

This is equivalent to the first option

---

[Documentation for `pd.read_csv`.](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas-read-csv)

Comment: Wonderful. The option #2 worked very well for csv files as well.

Comment: Neither of these options work if there is whitespace that does not separate out one field from another. If, e.g., you have a tab-delimited file, and there are spaces present inside a field, you pretty much have to do `sep='\t'`.

Comment: @AdrianKeister that is correct but the question deals with numeric data so we should be okay. But it is something to watch out for with string data.

Comment: it would be useful if it was either made clearer that we're only talking about numeric data, or a solution was provided for general csv data as well

Answer (score 14):

Another option is to use the built in CSV Sniffer. I mix it up with only reading a certain number of bytes in case the CSV file is large.

```
import csv

def get_delimiter(file_path, bytes = 4096):
    sniffer = csv.Sniffer()
    data = open(file_path, "r").read(bytes)
    delimiter = sniffer.sniff(data).delimiter
    return delimiter
```

Answer (score 5):

For better control, I use a python module called detect_delimiter from python projects. See https://pypi.org/project/detect-delimiter/ . It has been around for some time. As with all code, you should test with your interpreter prior to deployment. I have tested up to python version 3.8.5.

See code example below where the delimiter is automatically detected, and the var
delimiter is defined from the method's output. The code then reads the CSV file
with sep = delimiter. I have tested with the following delimiters, although others should work: ;  ,  |

It does not work with multi-char delimiters, such as ","

CAUTION! This method will do nothing to detect a malformed CSV file. In the case
where the input file contains both ; and , the method returns , as the detected delimiter.

```
from detect_delimiter import detect
import pandas as pd

filename = "some_csv.csv"
with open(filename) as f:
    firstline = f.readline()
    delimiter = detect(firstline)

records = pd.read_csv(filename, sep = delimiter)
```

Comment: There is a typo, it says `deliminter` where should say `delimiter`.

Comment: `detect_delimiter` doesn't consider quotation and escaping, and hence can easily miss the correct separator if it occurs more often because it's *escaped*. It counts the occurrence of the characters `,;:|` and tab in that order for each of the first 5 lines. If the default character occurs equally often in each line it's returned, else the first to occur equally often is returned, ... else the most occurring characters are tested in the same way, and if this also fails a the default is returned.